# node.js deploying on a static IP?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I attended a workshop for node.js application development and started exploring it. But what I had to do was start the server only on my local host and not on my static IP ( IP of my router which is connected to internet ). Is it possible to make my static IP a server and then access it from other places than local host only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open a forwarded port through your router to your node.js service. Make sure your server's local firewall (if any) allows incoming requests on the node.js server's listening port. How to do all this is router-specific and os-specific, so I can't offer anything more concrete.

Comment: Okay, yeah got the idea. I think I have a nat enabled router so i'll have to look into port mapping using NAT